# Passing parameters to qsort() function from <stdlib.h>

Tags: c, data-structures, std, qsort

This is the data type that I declared:

```
struct Element{
    char name[21], symbol[4];
    double atomicMass;
    int valence;
};
typedef struct Element myElements;
myElements data[20];
```

If I just want to pass the name members of

```
data[20]
```

to qsort(), how to do that?

Not sure if this would be the correct way to pass to the function:

```
qsort(data->name, 20, sizeof(myElements), compare);
```

Comment: Do you want to sort `data` by name alphabetically?

Comment: yeah by alphabetically.

Comment: "how to do that?" -- You don't do that, nor do you want to. What you want to do is sort your data based on the names. If you really really wanted pass just the names to qsort, you would have to copy them into an array consisting just of names.

Comment: `typedef struct Element myElements;` -- this is a good thing to do if you are competing in a C obfuscation contest. Otherwise, it should be `typedef struct Element Element;`

Answer (score 3):

You don't pass just member. Right way is to write a helper compare function which compares 2 elements by their name and use it.

```
static int
cmpElement(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    return strcmp(((const Element *) p1)->name, ((const Element *) p2)->name);
}

qsort(data, 20, sizeof data[0], cmpElement);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be
    sizeof(myElements)
instead of 
    sizeof(Element)

Comment: @SadmanAhmed No, sizeof(struct Element) or sizeof(data[0]) is correct; sizeof(myElements) is very wrong. Try reading the qsort documentation.

Comment: @JimBalter How is it different?

Comment: @JimBalter: `typedef struct Element myElements;`

Comment: Ah, you're right, but I reasonably expected myElements to be an array,  not a type of a single Element. That naming is horrible.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I see that now, but people have been hung for lesser crimes.